# Select2 con vuejs selected

Tags: vue.js, vuex

tengo un select2 que funciona bien, pero ahora lo que quiero hacer es que aparesca seleccionado (selected) una de las opciones.. alguna idea de como hacerlo, soy nuevo en utilizando VUE con laravel

[image: <code>introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí</code>]

```
<label>Año:</label><br>

<select2-vue :options="anhos" v-model="anho_id"></select2-vue>
```

//---------------------------------------------------------

```
 export default {
    data() {
        return {
            anhos: [],
            aulas: [],
            docentes: [],
            anho_id: null,
            aula_id:null,
            docente_id:null,
            hora_ingreso:'',
            hora_salida:''
        }
    },
    mounted() {

    },
    methods: {
        newHorario(){
            const params={
                anho_id: this.anho_id,
                aula_id: this.aula_id,
                docente_id: this.docente_id,
                hora_ingreso: this.hora_ingreso,
                hora_salida: this.hora_salida
            };
            this.resetForm();
            console.log("DATA",params)
            axios.post('/schedules',params)
                .then(
                    (response)=>{
                        const horario = response.data;
                         this.$emit('updateTable',horario);
                        $('#createHorario').modal('hide');
                        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                    }
                );


        },
        clickCreate() {
            axios.get('/getAnos').then((response) => {
                this.anhos = response.data;
            }),
            axios.get('/getAulas').then((response) => {
                this.aulas = response.data;
            }),
            axios.get('/getDocentes').then((response) => {
                this.docentes = response.data;

            })
        },
```

Comment: Solo necesitas en tu data cambiar anho_id: null, por un valor anho_id: 2019

Comment: Hola, si eso e hecho.. pero no funciona... e probado que si pongo mis datos estaticos en variable anhos, si funciona.. pero como lo lleno a traves de response.data no funciona.

Comment: Al pasarlo desde el response, debe vaciar la variable. Y si la asignas exactamente despues que le pasas el response?

Comment: 0: {__ob__: Observer}
1: {__ob__: Observer}
2: {__ob__: Observer}
Esto es lo que obtengo de mi variable anhos luego de darle el valor de response.data

Comment: No. asignale un valor que queres por defecto a anho_id, dentro del then cuando obtenes el valor traido de axios. Si no te lo pongo en una respuesta.